# ASR-1001-HX (license for crypto ipsec)

Tags: cisco, license

I have ASR-1001-HX with which I'm trying to run IPsec VPN.

But I don't have that option even with latest ios:

```
IPASR1#show ver | i bin
System image file is "bootflash:asr1000-universalk9.16.03.05.SPA.bin"
IPASR1#

IPASR1(config)#do show ver | inc cisco
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Cisco IOS-XE software, Copyright (c) 2005-2017 by cisco Systems, Inc.
http://www.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html
export@cisco.com.
cisco ASR1001-HX (1SR) processor (revision 1SR) with 3728915K/6147K bytes of memory.
IPASR1(config)#
```

I accepted all EULA but still no command.

```
IPASR1(config)#cryp ?
  key  Long term key operations
  pki  Public Key components

IPASR1(config)#cryp
```

How do I force the router enable all feature?

Thanks.

```
IPASR1(config)#do show lice all
License Store: Primary License Storage
StoreIndex: 0   Feature: adventerprise                     Version: 1.0
        License Type: Permanent
        License State: Active, In Use
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: Medium
License Store: Built-In License Storage
StoreIndex: 0   Feature: adventerprise                     Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Inactive
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 1   Feature: advipservices                     Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 2   Feature: avc                               Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 3   Feature: fwnat_red                         Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 4   Feature: ipsec                             Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 5   Feature: lawful_intr                       Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 6   Feature: lisp                              Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 7   Feature: otv                               Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 8   Feature: sw_redundancy                     Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 9   Feature: vpls                              Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 10  Feature: FoundationSuiteK9                 Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 11  Feature: AdvUCSuiteK9                      Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 12  Feature: 1HXIPS8G                          Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 13  Feature: 1HX8G16G                          Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 14  Feature: interface_10g                     Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, Not in Use, EULA not accepted
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Period used: 0  minute  0  second  
        License Count: 0/0  (In-use/Violation)
        License Priority: None
StoreIndex: 15  Feature: interface_1g                      Version: 1.0
        License Type: EvalRightToUse
        License State: Active, In Use
            Evaluation total period: 8  weeks 4  days 
            Evaluation period left: 4  weeks 2  days 
            Period used: 4  weeks 1  day  
            Transition date: Dec 22 2017 09:27:37
        License Count: 2/0  (In-use/Violation)
        License Priority: Low

IPASR1(config)#
```

Comment: Looks like the "ipsec" feature/license needs to be enabled. Read these: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/asr1000/install/guide/1001HX_1002HX/b_ASR1001HX-1002HX_HIG/b_ASR1001HX-1002HX_HIG_chapter_0110.html and https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/csa/command/csa-cr-book/csa-l1.html

Comment: already read to activate with no luck. will read again. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if the crypto module is present on the ASR.
You can check this with the help of show command "show version". On the ASRs which face such issues, its very much possible that the crypto module has not been installed. The show version in that case would look like:

```
cisco ASR1001-HX (1SR) processor (revision 1SR) with 3729260K/6147K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID TTM22100413
Crypto Hardware Module absent  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
8 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
8 Ten Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
3
```